# AngularJS injector not able to resolve a required dependency

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I'm traying to use Angular ui Notifications. When I tray to install it browser tells me  "Error: "[$injector:unpr]". The problem is that for me the dependencies are ok. The code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngTable', 'ui-notification']);

app.controller('clientesController', ['$scope', 'NgTableParams', 'ui-notification', 'clientesService',

    function ($scope, NgTableParams, Notification, clientesService) {
```

**EDIT:**
The way I'm pulling in my js files:

```
<!--Angular Files-->
    <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular-ui-notification.min.js"></script>
    <!-- App files-->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/clientes/clientesController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/clientes/clientesService.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please show how you're pulling in `ui-notifications` in your HTML (i.e. `script` tags)? AngularJS dependencies should be declared after `angular.js` is imported.

Comment: I edited the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification#service

> Module name: "ui-notification"
>
> **Service: "Notification"**
>
> Configuration provider: "NotificationProvider"

Change then name of the injected service to the correct name:

```
app.controller('clientesController', ['$scope', 'NgTableParams', 'Notification'...
```